# Avoid singularity in trigonometric calculation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm writing an algorithm to automatically place labels on pie chart sectors. I want to center the label in the largest circle that can be inscribed in the sector. Working in polar coordinates, the angle is obvious and the radius seems to be:

$$ \tan \theta \cdot \tan \left( \frac{ \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta  } { 2 } \right) $$

Where $\theta$ is equal to *half* the angle subtended by the sector (with a maximum of $90^\circ$)

Computing this directly (in JavaScript) runs into a removable singularity at $90^\circ$. Is there a reasonable way to modify the expression to avoid the singularity throughout the interval $[0, 90^\circ]$ (and increase numerical stability)? If all else fails, I can use two equations to cover the domain without singularities.

Comment: I fixed an error in the question. The singularity is an artifact of the equation, not the underlying problem. Values from 0 to $90^\circ$ are valid inputs; higher values are clamped (and lower values are impossible).

Comment: @YujieZha I don't follow your comment. That's a bit like saying the singularity of $\sin x/\tan x$ is unavoidable because tan goes to $0$ at $x=0$.  Even for practical purposes I imagine rewriting the expression to remove the singularity would be more numerically stable.

Comment: Let $\varphi = \frac{1}{2}\theta$. By the addition theorem, $$\tan \theta \cdot \tan \biggl(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\theta}{2}\biggr) = \frac{2\tan \varphi}{1 - \tan^2 \varphi}\cdot \frac{1-\tan \varphi}{1 + \tan \varphi} = \frac{2\tan \varphi}{(1+\tan \varphi)^2}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, that is exactly what I am looking for. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the formula to avoid singularities using the addition theorem of $\tan$. Whenever all expressions make sense, we have

$$\tan (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta}.$$

With $\varphi = \frac{1}{2}\theta$, and using $\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$, we obtain

\begin{align}
\tan \theta\cdot \tan\biggl(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\theta}{2}\biggr)
&= \tan (2\varphi)\cdot \tan\biggl(\frac{\pi}{4} - \varphi\biggr) \\
&= \frac{2\tan \varphi}{1 - \tan^2 \varphi}\cdot \frac{1 - \tan \varphi}{1 + \tan \varphi} \\
&= \frac{2\tan \varphi}{(1+\tan \varphi)^2},
\end{align}

which has no singularities in the domain under consideration.

Comment: This is perfect. Not only is it numerically stable, but as an added bonus there is only one tangent to compute.

Answer (score 2):

Wlog assume that the pie chart is centered on the origin and the sector angle is bisected by the $x$-axis. Let the radius of the sector be $r$. The equation of a line that bounds the sector is $x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta=0$. For $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2$, the center of the largest inscribed circle is the point on the $x$-axis which is equidistant from this line and the sector’s bounding circle. This condition yields the equation $r-x=x\sin\theta$, so $x={r\over1+\sin\theta}$.